# Laravel - redirect to a page with data and show it in view

Tags: laravel, redirect

I am using Laravel 5.8.32. 
In `web.php`, I have :

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/awesome', 'HomeController@doAwesome')->name('awesome');
```

In `HomeController`, I have :

```
public function index()
    {
        $a=230;
        return redirect()->route('awesome', ['a' => $a]);

    }//end of index function
```

In `awesome.blade.php` inside `views` folder, I have :

```
<?php
    echo "a = ".Session::get('a');
?>
```

No when I hit the URL `/home`, it goes to the URL `/awesome?a=230`. I get the output:`a=`. So you see that a blank value is printed. And at the sametime, the URL has a parameter, which I wish to remove.

**Q1)** how can I display the variable `$a` in view ?

**Q2)** how to remove the  parameter from the URL or should I keep it there as upon refresh if the parameter is absent in the URL , then variable value will not show in view ?  Any other way as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
`return redirect('awesome')->with('a', $a);`

Then you should be able to access `$a` within your blade template using either the blade syntax `{{$a}}` or accessing it directly using `Session::get('a');`

Comment: `Session::get('a');` gets an empty value and `{{$a}}` says - 'undefined variable'

Answer (score 0):

```
return redirect()->route('awesome', ['a' => $a]);
```

Here `a` is the route `uri` parameter as `route()` method defined-first argument is the `route name` and second argument is the list of `uri parameter`,it will show on your Url. Now, if we do in following ways-

```
public function index()
{
    $a=230;
    return redirect('awesome')->with('a',$a);
}
public function doAwesome()
{
    $a = session('a');
    return view('awesome')->with(['a' => $a]);
}
```

**Url** could not effected with `$a`,it will be just `/awesome` and to get this `$a` on your blade file-

```
<span>a={{ $a }}</span>
```

Comment: fix your `HomeController@doAwesome` method to catch those `var`

Comment: I have `$a=230;` within my controller method.

Comment: you need to set your `doAwesome` to handle that redirect action.

Comment: what do you mean ? A bit more explanation is necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205775/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-md-amirozzaman).

Answer (score 0):

Q1) how can I display the variable $a in view ?
You have to push your variable to session:
1 add this variable to session using Session::flash('a', $a);

```
public function index()
{
    $a=230;
    Session::flash('a', $a);
    return redirect()->route('awesome');
}
public function doAwesome()
{
    $a = Session::get('a');
    return view('awesome')->with(['a' => $a]);
}
```

Q2) how to remove the parameter from the URL or should I keep it there as upon refresh if the parameter is absent in the URL , then variable value will not show in view ? Any other way as well ?

above solution will work for this question too, but if you want to have this parameter for next refresh pages you should replace it with:

```
Session::push('a', $a);
```